# Getting results of execution ssh-client in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, function, ssh, return

I'm trying to retreive content of variable **stdout** from outside of ssh-client block in my code:

```
var SSH = require('simple-ssh');

var ssh = new SSH({
host: 'localhost',
user: 'username',
pass: 'password'
});

ssh.exec('echo $PATH', {
    out: function(stdout) {
    console.log(stdout);
}
}).start();
```

I need this variable's data, because in another part of code I need to parse it with another function (which deletes \n and removes '|' as delimiters with method "split") and write this information into Oracle database with oracledb-module.
Also I tried to associate ssh.exec with variable, like this:

```
var retreiveData = function ssh.exec('echo $PATH', {
    out: function(stdout) {
    console.log(stdout); // I tried to change it to "return stdout;"
}
}).start();
console.log(retrieveData());
```

But this didn't worked for me.
Please, help me.

Answer (score 1):

It is a callback pattern with async nature. So in order to persist the data represented by `stdout` returned in the `out` callback function handler, you need to do something along the line of

```
var SSH = require('simple-ssh');

function echo(callback) {
  var ssh = new SSH({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'username',
    pass: 'password'
  });

  var data = '';
  var error = null;

  ssh.exec('echo $PATH', {
    out: function(stdout) {
      data += stdout;
    },
    exit: function(code) {
      if (code != 0) return callback(new Error('exit code: ' + code));

      // here's all the data you have persisted from stdout
      return callback(error, data);
    },
    error: function(err) {
      error = err;
    }
  }).start();
}

echo(function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    // handle potential err
    console.error(err.stack);
  } else {
    // work with data as intended
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not detailed explanation..
Currently, I have output (stdout) only in terminal. But I need to continue working with this output in another functions. How I can work with this output in another function? 
So, is there something solution for something like this:
var abc function(){};  // ssh working here and exports stdout 
//...
///...
var xyz function(stdout){
//working with stdout here
}

Comment: @TomOzx i've updated the code in the answer. It's not tested, but you have to have a good grasp on the nature of asynchronous code in order to fully understand

Comment: unfortunately, when I added to  "out: " handler command `"console.log(stdout); "` , it's didn't put output to console and in  last rows of code: 
`function(data) { console.log(data);});` I didn't receive result too

Comment: @TomOzx my mistake in code and I think I made a mistake. Let me test the code and get back to you